# Apple Distribution Certificate doesn't include private keys when created from Apple Developer Portal

Tags: xcode, apple-developer

When I create a Apple Distribution Certificate or an iOS Distribution Certificate it doesn't include the private key even though it's a brand new certificate and it's worked this way for many years.

I've tried with 3 different apple developer accounts and every time I import the certificate in my keychain the private key isn't there, this means I can't export a p12 to build the archive in a CI/CD pipeline, or submit an app to the store.

I have tried logging in to apple developer as the account holder to see if it is a security feature but my certificate still did not hold a private key.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you archive the application (at least in XCode 11.1) when you submit to the app store it will complain that there is no private key and will not let you proceed.

However,

1. There is a 'manage certificates' in the bottom left of the dialog which will show all your certificates without their private keys.
2. Then there is another  button small '+' button in the bottom left of the dialog which will generate a new certificate and install it along with the private key in your keychain, it will the proceed to upload the app to the store. (at this point I had revoked all my certificates which may have made a difference)

You can then go an export the certificate from your keychain as normal.
I don't know if there is any other way of accessing this feature in XCode,  but this is the only way I've found of getting around this issue.

Comment: Also you can make clean Xcode (Cmd+Shift+K), then restart XCode. Afterward organizer will request password when you will try to upload your build, then the upload will complete successfully